# What to do in challenge "Hit back a log"?

Tags: once-upon-a-tower

The game Once Upon a Tower has a challenge that says "Hit back a log" but I don't understand what log, so I don't know how to complete it. Please be specific, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

the LOG would be the wood that is trying to crush you. you need to time it like when deflecting the fireballs.

i tested it on the horizontal LOG. waited for it to go in then i kept on hitting where the LOG will go out. successfule after several tries, seems it needs to be timed precisely.

Comment: Ok, Thank you.. do you have to go down many levels? Because I've never seen a log trying to hit me! The most far I've gotten is the the level where the small flying dragons appear

Comment: Oh wait... by Log do they mean the wood columns what hit the walls?